# How Can I check for a 0 ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a SQL query that may return an empty rowset.  I want to handle that with using a CASE statement.

This what I have tried but is not working

```
Case
When @@ROWCOUNT > 0 Then LTRIM(RTRIM(t.FirstName))  Else 'UNKNOWN'
End
```

The case statement does not return any value

If I use print @@RowCount rather then Select I get a 0 value.

How can I solve this?

Okay the query is rather large so I'll try to explain what it does.  I am using this in a function that returns data from our HR database.  I need Employee information such as name and work assignments. There are cases where I need to process the data where the employee is unknown.  In those cases I pass an employeeId number of zero.  That results in an empty return when I run the query.

What I would like to do is have the function return the Name data as UNKNOWN.

Hope this helps clear up the request a little

I have trimmed up the query so I can show all of the relevant parts below:

```
DECLARE @EID int = 0
DECLARE @AssignmentType varchar(max) = 'FirstName'
DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(max)
DECLARE @EIDTemp TABLE(EID varchar(6), Section varchar(max), Division 
varchar(max), Bureau varchar(max), FirstName varchar(max), MiddleName 
varchar(max), LastName varchar(max));

Insert Into @EIDTemp
SELECT L1.Employee, P1.NAME As Section,
CASE 
    WHEN L1.DEPARTMENT IN (7010) THEN 'Legal Services Division' 
    WHEN L1.DEPARTMENT IN (7030,7040) THEN 'Fiscal Management Division'
    Else 'Other'
END AS Division,
CASE
    WHEN L1.DEPARTMENT IN (7130) THEN 'Administrative Services Bureau'
    ELSE ','
END As Bureau
,L1.FIRST_NAME
,L1.MIDDLE_NAME
,L1.LAST_NAME
FROM [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.EMPLOYEE L1
 JOIN [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.DEPTCODE L2 ON L1.Department = 
L2.Department
 JOIN [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.JOBCODE L3 on L1.JOB_CODE = L3.JOB_CODE
 JOIN [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.PRSYSTEM P1 ON L1.PROCESS_LEVEL = 
p1.PROCESS_LEVEL
WHERE  L1.EMP_STATUS='A1'


-- Select the Return Value
-------------------------------


IF (@AssignmentType = 'FirstName')
BEGIN
SET @ReturnValue = (SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(t.MiddleName)) From @EIDTemp t 
where EID = @EID);
END

IF (@AssignmentType = 'MiddleName')
BEGIN
SET @ReturnValue = (SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(t.MiddleName)) From @EIDTemp t 
where EID = @EID);
END

IF (@AssignmentType = 'LastName')
BEGIN
SET @ReturnValue = (SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(t.LastName)) From @EIDTemp t 
where EID = @EID);
END
```

Comment: You aren't showing all of your logic.  Can you use `If Exists` instead of the row count?

Comment: Try setting @@RowCount to a variable before this block of code perhaps.

Comment: Post the whole query and explain what you are trying to do. Remember that @@ROWCOUNT returns the number of rows int he LAST statement. I have a feeling you are trying to see if the current query has no rows.

Comment: cont from Sean Lange's comment ... and if your last statement has 0 rows then you might want to validate the record set prior to doing something to those rows. Coming full circle this is why ps2goat suggested if exists, this would be used before you do something to your record set to validate you have a record set

Comment: wish there is `peek` function in sql server

Comment: I have added more information to the question.  The query is rather large so I did not want to post all of it.

Comment: Can you write enough of the query to reproduce the problem?   There is nothing wrong in the part of the code you have posted so far.   The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: As I thought....the problem is a logical one. You are trying to evaluate if the current query is returning no rows inside the query itself. This will never work. You need to run your query and THEN check @@ROWCOUNT. You are currently trying to return a value in a row that doesn't exist.

Comment: If you really want some help you need to post enough of the details around this query so we know what is going on. You don't have to post hundreds of lines of a query but enough so that we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have trimmed the query down to be able to post all of it for review  thanks for your assistance

Comment: @Perry, if you need a query to always return a minimum of one row (possibly with a default value), then simply write that into the query. Start with a single row consisting of the default value(s), and left-join it unconditionally against the results which may consist of zero rows, and then include some conditional logic to substitute the default value into the columns which ought to carry the default value.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments and suggestion a co-worker suggested a code change which worked out for me.  I posted to new code for anyone that's interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker of mine solved the problem by checking the value of the Employee ID at the start and returning UNKNOWN with this code

```
> DECLARE @EID int = 0
DECLARE @AssignmentType varchar(max) = 'FirstName'

DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(max) = 'UNKNOWN'
DECLARE @EIDTemp TABLE(EID varchar(6), Section varchar(max), Division 
varchar(max), Bureau varchar(max), FirstName varchar(max), MiddleName 
varchar(max), LastName varchar(max));

if @EID = 0
   goto done

-- Insert into a Temp Table
-------------------------------
Insert Into @EIDTemp
SELECT L1.Employee, P1.NAME As Section,
   CASE 
          WHEN L1.DEPARTMENT IN (7010) THEN 'Legal Services Division' 
          WHEN L1.DEPARTMENT IN (7030,7040) THEN 'Fiscal Management 
Division'
          Else 'Other'
   END AS Division,
   CASE
          WHEN L1.DEPARTMENT IN (7130) THEN 'Administrative Services Bureau'
          ELSE ','
   END As Bureau
   ,L1.FIRST_NAME
   ,L1.MIDDLE_NAME
   ,L1.LAST_NAME
FROM [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.EMPLOYEE L1
   JOIN [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.DEPTCODE L2 ON L1.Department = 
L2.Department
   JOIN [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.JOBCODE L3 on L1.JOB_CODE = 
L3.JOB_CODE
   JOIN [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.PRSYSTEM P1 ON L1.PROCESS_LEVEL = 
p1.PROCESS_LEVEL
WHERE  L1.EMP_STATUS='A1' AND l1.EMPLOYEE = @EID


-- Select the Return Value
-------------------------------


IF (@AssignmentType = 'FirstName')
BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = (SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(t.FirstName)) From @EIDTemp 
t where EID = @EID);
END

IF (@AssignmentType = 'MiddleName')
BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = (SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(t.MiddleName)) From 
@EIDTemp t where EID = @EID);
END

IF (@AssignmentType = 'LastName')
BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = (SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(t.LastName)) From @EIDTemp 
t where EID = @EID);
END

done:

print @ReturnValue
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you are setting your variables. When you use SET it will change the value to NULL if no rows are returned.

You should instead change up your code so it does something like this.

```
SET @ReturnValue = 'Unknown'

IF (@AssignmentType = 'FirstName')
BEGIN
SELECT @ReturnValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(t.MiddleName)) From @EIDTemp t 
where EID = @EID
END
```

This sets an initial value to Unknown. This would be before all of your IF statements and would work across the whole collection. If there are no rows returned the value will remain unchanged. I removed the TOP 1 because it is not needed. If you have multiple rows it will receive the value from the last row in the result set. If there are lots of rows you could always use MAX or MIN.

Answer (score 1):

@Perry, is the following more like what you are looking for:

```
WITH employee_ids AS
(
    SELECT 
        emp.Employee AS eid
        ,P1.NAME As Section
        ,CASE 
            WHEN emp.DEPARTMENT IN (7010) THEN 
                'Legal Services Division' 
            WHEN emp.DEPARTMENT IN (7030,7040) THEN 
                'Fiscal Management Division'
            ELSE
                'Other'
            END AS Division
        ,CASE
            WHEN emp.DEPARTMENT IN (7130) THEN 
                'Administrative Services Bureau'
            ELSE 
                ','
            END As Bureau
        ,emp.FIRST_NAME
        ,emp.MIDDLE_NAME
        ,emp.LAST_NAME
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.EMPLOYEE) AS eid_match

    FROM
        [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.EMPLOYEE AS emp

    INNER JOIN 
        [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.DEPTCODE AS depts 
        ON (emp.Department = depts.Department)

    INNER JOIN 
        [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.JOBCODE AS jcs 
        ON (emp.JOB_CODE = jcs.JOB_CODE)

    INNER JOIN 
        [SOOPS-LAWREPT].[LAWDATA].dbo.PRSYSTEM AS prs 
        ON (emp.PROCESS_LEVEL = prs.PROCESS_LEVEL)

    WHERE
        emp.EMP_STATUS='A1'
)
,provisional_results AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE @AssignmentType
            WHEN 'FirstName' THEN
                employee_ids.FirstName
            WHEN 'MiddleName' THEN
                employee_ids.MiddleName
            WHEN 'LastName' THEN
                employee_ids.LastName
            ELSE
                NULL
            END AS provisional_return_value

    FROM 
        (VALUES (0)) AS default_values(default_value)

    LEFT JOIN 
        employee_ids
        ON (employee_ids.eid = @eid) 
        AND (eid_match = 1)
)
SELECT 
    @ReturnValue = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(provisional_return_value)), 'UNKNOWN') 
FROM 
    provisional_results
```

I haven't tested the code as I'm not at my desktop so excuse any small syntax errors, but it should achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the `@@RowCount` variable immediately after running the insert/select and return the variable. If you don't save the variable, another statement will eventually clear the rowcount...

**Example:**

```
--Variable to hold the rowcount
DECLARE @Count int = 0
...

Insert Into @EIDTemp
SELECT L1.Employee, P1.NAME As Section,
...
WHERE  L1.EMP_STATUS='A1'

--Save the result
SELECT @Count=@@RowCount

...
--Use the saved result
Case
    When @Count > 0 Then LTRIM(RTRIM(t.FirstName))  Else 'UNKNOWN'
End
```